# Dundas bi. Chart embedding in React

Tags: reactjs, dundas

How to embed a dundas bi chart in a React app. Has anyone worked with this?
When I try to do this I get an error - The cookies required to operate are being blocked by the browser.

Comment: I get a logon token, I’m trying to insert a chart using the .create method
GetSession request returns 440 error